# in Django parameter in reverse never gets interpreted

Tags: python, django, url, parameter-passing, reverse

In Django 1.6, I have a view with a link that is a reverse with a parameter:

```
edit_link = """<a href="%s"><img src="icon.gif"></a>""" % reverse('bio_filter', args={'ename':row.entity_name})
```

In my urls.py file, the pattern of the url associated with the bio_filter view is:

```
url(
    regex=ur'^filter/(?P<ename>.*)/$',
    view=bio_filter_view,
    name='bio_filter',
),
```

Finally, in the views file of the bio_filter, I have this function:

```
def bio_filter_view(request,ename):
```

The problem is that the ename parameter never gets the value of entity_name. If I print in the function the ename variable, the value is literally 'ename'!
What am I missing?

Regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` expects a list or iterable of positional arguments. What you should be using is `kwargs`, short for keyword arguments, which expects a dictionary of named arguments.

```
reverse('bio_filter', kwargs={'ename': row.entity_name})
```

The reason you see the literal `'ename'` in the url is that `args` accepts any iterable. You *can* iterate over a dictionary, but you're actually iterating over its keys. Thus, passing `{'ename': row.entity_name}` to `args` has the same effect as passing `['ename']` to `args`!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `kwargs` argument instead of `args`:

```
reverse('bio_filter', kwargs={'ename': row.entity_name})
```

Another option is to use the positional group of regex:

```
reverse('bio_filter', args=[row.entity_name])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `args` and `kwargs` here.

```
>>>reverse('bio_filter', kwargs={'ename': "entity_value"})
'/filter/entity_value'
```

OR

```
>>>reverse('bio_filter', args=["entity_value"])
'/filter/entity_value'
```